# Inexplicable EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I'm getting an intermittent EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on my app and I have no idea why.  It's a method that connects to my back end that has been working for years and is now blowing up 
unpredictably.

```
- (BOOL)isServerAvailable {

    if (SharedAppDelegate.netConnectionUp) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/is_server_online", API_BASE_URL]];
        NSError *theNetworkError = nil;
        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&theNetworkError];

       if ([content isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {

            return YES;
       }
       else {

            [self showNoServerDialog];
       }
    }
```

The debugger indicates that it's dying on the:

```
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&theNetworkError];
```

I've got no idea why. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the value of `url` just before the exception occurs?

Comment: @Drux The value is correct in the debugger variable. It's the complete url to my back end /is_server_online API call.

Comment: What is the address reported with the exception? `0x0` or some non-zero value? Is `API_BASE_URL` a constant or a variable? I might suggest adding your own `NSAssert(url, @"URL is nil");` before the `stringWithContentsOfURL` call, that way you'll be able to determine whether problem is the URL or `stringWithContentsOfURL`.

Comment: @Rob The address reported with the exception is 0x1. The API_BASE_URL is a constant located in the app delegate.  Thanks for the suggestion on the NSAssert, the application successfully passes the assert and still crashes on the stringWithContentsOfURL.

Comment: An address of 0x1 seems very strange (a "code" of 0x1 makes sense, but not an "address" of 0x1). Zero addresses suggest one category of problem, and non-zero (yet still plausible) addresses suggest another. An address of 0x1, if that's really true, suggests something radically different. All of that notwithstanding, I cannot reproduce your problem (and we cannot fix that which I cannot reproduce). Perhaps you can create a demonstration that manifests this issue.